# Sentence constructors and parts

Tags: sentence-construction, parts-of-speech, functions

What are all the parts a sentence can be made of?

Noun, verb, adjective, pronoun, adverb etc. And what is a short description of the function of each?

I know these can be found online and in text books but they tend to be spread out over many chapters or volumes even.
Or are there books/websites showing this all on one page with a short description.

Comment: See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech

Comment: Post this question on ELL, -you'll get a much better answer there than you will here, I promise :) Here you'd get rubbish like *nouns are subjects* or *nouns are things* or *adverbs describe verbs*! It may be called ELL but there's some serious grammarians over there, and everyone's welcome to ask questions :)

Comment: Well, there's categories of stuff, like noun, noun phrase (NP), verb, verb phrase (VP), adjective, etc.; and then there's grammatical function within a structure, for example in the structure of a clause are functions like subject, predicator/verb, object, predicative complement, etc. You'll probably want to get a copy of a good modern textbook on grammar, such as the 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*. (cont.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach The section on English in that article is criminally poor :( [Verbs are actions, pleugh]

Comment: @Araucaria I suggested Wikipedia as a starting point for research. But the article is editable, if there is scope for improvement above primary-school descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Andrew said, the **parts of speech** are all the different types of words: nouns, verbs, etc. Towson University has a decent, if somewhat old, [guide](http://www.towson.edu/ows/index.asp) online for English. The guide goes into the different roles and functions each part of speech can have in a sentence.

Other languages have other elements, such as particles or tones, that English does not have.

Comment: That does not address the functions side of this question though! :)

Comment: @Araucaria - Now it does! ^_^ The guide explains them, at least partially. A full answer would take an entire textbook.

Comment: I'll accept this, as it points one into the right direction with a centralised place to get the answers.

Comment: @McGafter Crumbs, don't give up that easily - anyone trying to answer this is going to be taking a wee bit of time if they're going to do it properly! :)